# Why is AIR NativeProcess not supported?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I'm building a desktop app using Flash Builder and I need it to run a .exe program. I downloaded and installed the latest AIR SDK, put it in my Flash Builder sdks folder and had my project use it. Now i don't have any compiler errors, but:

```
     if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
            {
                var file:File = new File("C:\Torres.exe");
                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
                var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            }
```

I checked and it just never goes inside the if block. Why wouldn't nativeprocess be supported? Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is a bit of a necro post and slightly inapplicable, BUT - if anyone is running into this problem testing from the normal Flash Pro IDE, getting the " Error: Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'Not supported in current profile.' " error - check your AIR publish options. It will support the NativeProcess functionality if *only* 'extended desktop' box under the 'profiles' section is selected. if 'desktop' is also selected, it'll default to that, and you'll be left without proper permissions. (this is for Flash Pro CC, btw.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

to your app's manifest file. Using NativeProcess requires extended rights.

The article is likely to be helpful: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_screenrecording.html

Comment: Ok, I added that line to my descriptor and now the flow goes inside the if block, but still I can't run my other exe. It just does nothing

Comment: Surely, you did check this: Does C:\Torres.exe execute in cmd.exe? Does Torres.exe exist in the root folder of C: ?

Comment: Ok, stupid mistake the path needed a slash (/) instead of a backslash (\). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Possibilities:

1. Your AIR Runtime not 2.0 or Later version. Because NativeProcess supports in 2.0 and Later version only.

   You can check your Adobe AIR runtime version in two ways.
   a) Manual
   b) By Coding

   *a) Manual*

   - In Windows : Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Select Adobe AIR -> Click the link "*Click here for support information*"
   - In MAC OSx : Finder Window -> Select Application -> Select Adobe AIR Installer ->  Right Click -> Select "Get Info"

   *b) By Coding*

   Paste this code in your Desktop Application to find the AIR runtime version.

   > trace(nativeApplication.runtimeVersion); // 2.6.0.19120
2. Your not mentioned **"extendedDesktop"** value in the **"supportedProfiles"** property in the Application Descriptor file or Your not enable that property.

   > <supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>